# Is it possible to make a customisable & reusable SwiftUI Form?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want the to be able to create a `Form` in SwiftUI by creating a custom model and defining what fields are needed. Eventually, I want the User to be able to do this to make their own custom forms and data models, but for now I just want to reduce the code so that I can just quickly "Write" different types of `Form` and use a For loop to generate the form.

I.e. I have basically duplicate pages of code for different types of forms, which all work the same but just have different values and it seems like a waste, and I could just have some kind of single view and feed the data needed to that so I can reuse it, and eventually allow users to create their own custom forms in the future.

Here is what I have come up with so far as an example (Just playing around and trying to see what might be possible):

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation


var fieldTypes = ["Field", "Slider", "List", "Date"...]


struct Worksheet: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {

//data for populating Form
var id: String
var name: String?
var fields: [Field]

//data for saving model and values of form
var title: String?
var date: Date
var severity: Double
var trigger: String?
var description: String
var symptoms: [String]
var nInterpretation: String?
var rResponse: String

}
    
struct Field: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {

var id: String
var type: String
var title: String
var description: String
var footer: String
        
}

class Dev_VM: ObservableObject {

var fields = [Field(id: "i", type: "Slider", title: "SliderTitle", description: "Description", footer: "Footer"), Field(id: "id2", type: "TextField", title: "TextFieldTitle", description: "Description", footer: "Footer")]

}

//Form view for data entry
struct Dev_FormView: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
@ObservedObject var vm = Dev_VM()

static let taskDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
       return dateFormatter
   }()

var body: some View {
        Form {
            //Section for selecting date.
            
            for field in vm.fields {
            
                switch field.type {
                case "TextField":
                    Section(header: Text(field.title), footer: Text(field.footer)) {
                    
                        ZStack {
                            TextEditor(text: $title)
                            .disabled(!editMode)
                               
Text(title).opacity(0).padding(.all, 8)
                           }
                      
                    }
                    
                case "Slider":
                    HStack {
                    Slider(value: $value, in: 0...100, step: 1)
                            .disabled(true)
                                Text("\(Int(severity))")
                    }
                default:
                    print("Empty")
                }
                    
            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Dev_Playground", displayMode: .inline)
    
}

}
```

Seems that there are problems, for example on the for statement I get the error `Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'`

Another problem seems to be populating the values, as I will need `@State` variables, because the fields are dynamic, could I make these dynamic too?

Does anyone think that what I'm trying to do might be possible? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. This is possible

Comment: Use an array of enum instead of an array of strings. The enum can then hold onto the model for the field.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are not familiar at all with how SwiftUI works. For loops don’t work that way in SwiftUI. You should use a ForEach view.